# Is this a working way to design a sequencer and an oscillator connected to each other?

Tags: oscillator, design, counter

[image]

I would like to build a sequencer that controls an oscillator. I attached the schematics. The basic principles are that R_1 and R_2 are chosen, so that they yield a voltage of 0.7V at point D approximately. This voltage is further divided by the pot R, 100k, and R_3, so that the voltage that arrives to the transistor is in the right range - around 0.3V to 0.5V - according to the settings of the pot R. This part, not including the transistor, is repeated, say, 5 times on the outputs of the counter chip, yielding a way of playing a different sound at each step (5 step sequencer). The transistor acts as a voltage controlled resistor (or is it?). The other part of the circuit is an inverted Schmitt trigger and a capacitor and the "voltage controlled resistor" (the transistor) forming a voltage controlled oscillator: this is what produces the oscillation - with a frequency controlled by the "sequencer".

Should I put a resistor at point A, for safety reasons?

Should I buffer the output of the sequencer (the counter chip) after the diodes , at point B, (say with a tl074 op amp).

Is this the right way to achive a lower voltage from a higher one: that is the "device" made of R_1 , R, and R_2 and R_3?
I would choose large values for R1 and R2, say R1 is 10k and R2 is , say, 400k, R3 large also. This way the current flowing to ground is minimal: is this a good strategy?

Please point out my design flows!

I would like to add that this is my design, put together from different thing I found on the internet: so I am most probably doing wrong several things.

Comment: You can and should simulate the oscillator part in CircuitLab built into this site (don’t go offsite - stay in the question editor). That will tell you whether the oscillator works the way you want it to. That’s before you even think about any sequencing. Basics first. Controlling a transistor conductance tightly open-loop is nigh impossible so the idea will “work” but the frequency will drift. It’s easier to use a digitally controlled oscillator with a divider and a PLL. That will stay rock solid. Or even a 555 with a variable threshold voltage will be more stable than the single transistor.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica part 1 of comment: Ok, so I probably have not managed to put on the question the right way. So, I wanted to know, if in general, what I am doing is not total nonsense. The sequencer is a simple counter-divider IC, the cd4017. It is fed a clock signal (not drawn on the picture nor mentioned in the question), and when there is pulse on the clock, it turns of the nth output and turns on the n+1th (all outputs except one are off always).

Comment: part 2 of comment:  @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica

This is what gives the basis of the sequencer. At each output there is a pot-controllable voltage, which is fed into the transistor, and the transistor acts as a variable resistor (if it is fed with voltages below 0.7V). 

It is for a very basic musical synth: the oscillator drawn on the figure, the oscillator built with the Schmitt trigger and the capacitor.

Comment: part 3 of comment:  @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica The 4017 chip cycles through its output according to the clock signal, and at each "step" it yields a different voltage on the transistor, and thus, at each step a different oscillation frequency is manifested on the module built by the Schmitt and the cap.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Will it drift because of temperature changes? Could you point me to some place I can learn what "Controlling a transistor conductance tightly open-loop" means? What is open-loop? And, what does "tightly" means here?

Comment: Open loop is like driving a car with your eyes closed. Assuming you steer the car in the right direction, you might be ok. Closed loop is when you open your eyes and compensate for any discrepancy in the direction you want to go. So feeding a given voltage into your simple transistor circuit  is open loop. Temperature changes will cause the transistor to drift. Your sequencer concept is valid, your VCO is not. Look at using a 555 ic with the sequencer selecting different resistances for the 555 ic in astable mode. Search for ‘astable 555’ for examples.